# React: Issue with message item for chat UI

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I'm working on a reac-native chat app, I want to add a samll image of the user to the left of each message, the image will appear only if:

1. The previous message belongs to my user
2. If the user sent multiple messages in a row, the image will only appear on the last received one.

To better understand what I'm trying to do check this image (look at the column on the left, the little image with user default image)

https://i.imgur.com/CaKltON.jpg

Each message object has a user_id value which is the id of the user that sent the message
I store messages in root.mapStore.activeChatMessages mobx value and pass each message and index as a prop to MessageCard

FlatList component

```
<FlatList 
            vertical={true} 
            data={root.mapStore.activeChatMessages} keyExtractor={item => item.provisionalId.toString()}
            renderItem={({ item, index }) => 
            <MessageCard1 item={item} index={index}></MessageCard1>
            
            }
            />
```

MessageCard

```
export default MessageCard= observer((props) => 
{
    
    const { item, index } = props;

    const showUserImage = () =>
    {
        //Put logic here
    };

    return (
    <View style={{ width:'60% , flexDirection:'row',alignItems:'center }}>
        { showUserImage() && (
            <Image></Image>
        )}
        <Text>{ item.messageBody }</Text>
    </View>

);

});
```

Answer (score 0):

To implement the logic you described, you need to compare the `user_id` of the current message with the `user_id` of the previous message. If they are the same, you also need to check if the next message (if it exists) has a different `user_id`. If it does, then you show the image.

Here's how you can implement this logic in your `showUserImage` function:

```
jsx
const showUserImage = () => {
    const previousMessage = root.mapStore.activeChatMessages[index - 1];
    const nextMessage = root.mapStore.activeChatMessages[index + 1];

    // If there's no previous message or the previous message is from a different user, don't show the image
    if (!previousMessage || previousMessage.user_id !== item.user_id) {
        return false;
    }

    // If there's no next message or the next message is from a different user, show the image
    if (!nextMessage || nextMessage.user_id !== item.user_id) {
        return true;
    }

    // If none of the above conditions are met, don't show the image
    return false;
};
```

This function checks if the previous message exists and if it's from the same user. If it's not, the function returns `false`, meaning the image should not be shown. If the previous message is from the same user, the function then checks if the next message exists and if it's from a different user. If it is, the function returns `true`, meaning the image should be shown. If the next message is from the same user, the function returns `false`.

Please note that this function assumes that the `root.mapStore.activeChatMessages` array is sorted in ascending order by the time the messages were sent. If this is not the case, you might need to sort the array before using this function.